# Polynomial division modulo $7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> We are given polynomials $f(x)=x^5+2x^4+3x^3+4x^2+5x+6,\ g(x)=3x^3+x$ in the polynomial ring $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})[x]$. I want to find the polynomials $q,r$ for which $f=gq+r$. Note that $deg(r)<deg(q)$

Attempt:

Either $r=0$, or $r\ne 0$ and $\deg(r)<\deg(q)$. Note that $\deg(q)=\deg(f)-\deg(g)=2$. Hence $\deg(r)=1$. As such we can write $q(x)=ax^2+bx+c, \ r(x)=cx+d.$ Performing the multiplication we obtain $$x^5+2x^4+3x^3+4x^2+5x+6=(3x^3+x)(ax^2+bx+c)+dx+e.$$

Expanding and simplifying, this reduces to $$x^5+2x^4+3x^3+4x^2+5x+6=3ax^5+3bx^4+(3c+a)x^3+bx^2+(c+d)x+e$$

We immediately see that $b=4$ as it is the coefficient of $x^2$. Further we have;

$[3a]=1$ and so $[a]=5$

$[3b]=2$ so $[b]=3$

$[3c+a]=3$ so $[c]=4$

$[c+d]=5$ so $[d]=1$, and $[e]=6$

This gives $f(x)=g(x)(5x^2+4x+4)+(x+6)$, but this equality is actually incorrect upon expanding.

Checking $b=4$ in the coefficient of $x^4$ we get $4\times 3\equiv 5\bmod 7$ which isn't what we want. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I haven't checked all of the above, but stopped at the statement $\deg(r) < \deg(q)$.  Why should this be true?

Comment: You can [do it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=polynomialquotientremainder%5Bx%5E5%2B2x%5E4%2B3x%5E3%2B24x%5E2%2B5x%2B6%2C3x%5E3%2Bx%2Cx%5D) in $\mathbb Q[x]$ and then reduce mod $7$.

Comment: Was the problem statement supposed to include the condition that $\deg(r) < \deg(q)$? Or did it originally use words such as "polynomial division with remainder"? Without such a condition, doesn't the solution set include all pairs $(q,r)$ where $q$ is any member of the polynomial ring and $r = f - gq$? (Yes, you do say "polynomial division" in the title, but one expects a complete problem statement in the question itself.)

Comment: @DavidK indeed this condition is in the question, I've edited it

Comment: We both forgot how polynomial division actually works: the remainder has a lower degree than the *divisor,* not a lower degree than the *quotient.* In this case there is no solution with $\deg(r)<\deg(q),$ but there is a solution with $\deg(r)<\deg(g).$ The step where you set $b=4$ is still incorrect.

Comment: @DavidK why is it incorrect to set $b=4$?

Comment: There's no justification to set $b=4.$ Also, later, we find out that actually $b\equiv 3 \pmod 7.$

Answer (score 1):

Your coefficient of $24x^2$ in the original problem changed to $4x^2$, but with reduction mod $7$, it should change to $3x^2$. This should also help resolve in your solution that in one place $b=3$ and in another $b=4$.

---

Edit after revision of problem:

The remainder polynomial is potentially of degree $2$. That is $\deg(r)<\deg(g)=3$. [Not $\deg(r)<\deg(q)=2$.]

Comment: It's $4x^2$ sorry

Comment: Ah I see that's an issue - so we now set $r(x)=px^2+qx+r$ and do essentially the same argument again?